# Pass an Serializable object in AIDL

Tags: android, aidl

I have defined an **aidl** file

```
interface IMyFeature {
    void doTask(Class clazz);
}
```

But I need to pass an [`Class` object](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Class.html) to another process. Is it possible in Android? If so, how?

I tried:

```
interface IMyFeature {
    Serializable Class;
    void doTask(Class clazz);
}
```

But it doesn’t work.

Answer (score 1):

AIDL in Android only supports custom class which implement the `Parcelable` interface.

In your case you want to send a Class object which is not possible. What you can do is send the class canonical name and retrieve it in your service.

For example you could have this aidl file

```
interface IMyFeature { 
    void doTask(String className);
}
```

Then call it like this :

```
binder.doTask(MyClass.class.getCanonicalName());
```

And finally in your service Binder stub implementation :

private

```
 final IMyFeature mBinder = new IMyFeature.Stub() {



        public void doTask(String className) {

            try {
                Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className);

                Constructor<?> ctor = clazz.getConstructor((Class[]) null);

                Object object = ctor.newInstance();

            } catch (Exception e) {
               // 
            }

        }
    };
```